# Fill column with constant predefined values in random order

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to replace values in existing column with predefined constant values.
Let's say we have a table:

| id | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | x |
| 355 | x |
| 122 | x |
| 352 | x |
| ... | ... |
| 355 | x |

Now, I need in the columns id to replace the values with 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', in random order, like:

| id | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| cc | x |
| aa | x |
| cc | x |
| bb | x |
| ... | ... |
| aa | x |

Thanks in advance!

First I tried to create a new column with fixed values but run into an error:

```
select id, Column_B, 
['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] as new_col
from my_table
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [random](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RANDOM.html) function within a case expression as the following:

```
select *,
   case cast(random()*2 as int) +1 
     when 1 then 'aa'
     when 2 then 'bb'
     when 3 then 'cc'
   end as new_col
from tbl
```

[demo on Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/QCoE930f)